# Blog Submit function saves post to database but won't display blog post in angular component

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am trying to create a blog with angular and mongodb. When I submit my blog, it is saved in the database (checked using postman). The data I enter in the input tags and ckeditor also appears in the mat-card component when I tested it. But when I try to submit the blog it does not display in the blog-page component. The blog gets stored in the db. Something is wrong with my onBlogSubmit() function but I can't figure out what it is:

This is what I tried:

My post.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from '../post/post';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export interface post {
  success: boolean;
  post: any;
  token: any;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PostService {
  authToken: any;
  post: any;
  public baseUri: string = 'http://localhost:3000/blogs';
  public headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPosts(): Observable<post> {
    this.loadToken();
    const head = this.headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    return this.http.get<post>(this.baseUri + '/allPosts', { headers: head });
  }

  getPost(id): Observable<post> {
    this.loadToken();
    const head = this.headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    return this.http.get<post>(this.baseUri + '/singlePost/' + id, { headers: head })
  }

  addPost(post): Observable<post> {
    this.loadToken();
    const head = this.headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    return this.http.post<post>(this.baseUri + '/newPost', post, { headers: head });
  }

  updatePost(id, post: post): Observable<any> {
    this.loadToken();
    const head = this.headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    return this.http.put<post>(this.baseUri + '/editPost/' +id , post, { headers: head });
  }

  deletePost(id): Observable<post> {
    this.loadToken();
    const head = this.headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    return this.http.put<post>(this.baseUri + '/deletePost/' + id, { headers: head });
  }


  public loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }
}
```

My blog-add component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../Services/post.service';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-add',
  templateUrl: './blog-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-add.component.scss']
})

export class BlogAddComponent implements OnInit {

    postTitle: string;
    postAuthor: string;
    postContent: string;
    postImgUrl: string;
    post = {};

  constructor(private postService: PostService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
  }

// THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS
  onBlogSubmit() {
    const post = {
      postTitle: this.postTitle,
      postAuthor: this.postAuthor,
      postContent: this.postContent,
      postImgUrl: this.postImgUrl
    }

    this.postService.addPost(post).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success) {
        this.postService.getPosts();
        this.flashMessage.show('Blog Submitted Successfully', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000});
        this.router.navigate(['/blog-page']);
      } else {
        this.flashMessage.show('Something Went Wrong', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
      }
    });
  }

}
```

My blog-add component HTML:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="row" *ngIf="post">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-main">
      <form name="postForm" (ngsubmit)="onBlogSubmit()" class="text-center border border-light p-5 shadow-lg">

        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="post.postTitle" name="postTitle">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="post.postAuthor" name="postAuthor">
          <img ng-src="postImgUrl">
          <ckeditor matCkeditor class="form-control mb-8" [(ngModel)]="post.postContent" name="postContent"></ckeditor>
          <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block get" (click)="onBlogSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My blog-page ts file where I want to view the blog data.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../Services/post.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-page',
  templateUrl: './blog-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-page.component.scss']
})
export class BlogPageComponent implements OnInit {
    post: Object;

  constructor(private postService: PostService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
        this.post = posts.post;
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false; 
    });
  }

}
```

My blog-page component HTML:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <mat-card *ngIf="post" class="card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title class="title">{{post.postTitle}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle class="subtitle">Author: {{post.postAuthor}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-card-subtitle class="subtitle">Content: {{post.postContent}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-actions class="multi-button">
        <button mat-icon-button><span class="fa fa-share fa-lg"></span></button>
        <button mat-icon-button><span class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></span></button>
        <!-- <button mat-icon-button><span class="fa fa-heart fa-lg"></span></button> -->
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
  </div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

There are no errors in the console or in the browser. The blog just doesn't submit and gives the error message I programmed into it. I have not been able to figure out the problem. I have tested whether the data I enter in the input and ckeditor appears in the mat-card module and it works fine. Please could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: what does your `data` response look like?  I would `console.log(data)` to verify it has `.success` property.

Comment: The console.log shows the _id and updated value. It does not show the postTitle, postContent etc.

Comment: If you don't have a `success` property, then your condition will always return `false` and treat it like an error: `if(data.success)`

Comment: I added the success property to my export interface and used it in the ts. There were no typescript errors. So How can I solve this?

Comment: What does your endpoint look like? Sounds like it isn't retrieving the correct stuff.

Comment: The endpoint for the blogposts on my express server is this:           `router.get('/allPosts', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
    const token = getToken(req.headers);
    if (token) {
        Post.find(function (err, posts) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(posts);
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Unauthorized.'});
    }
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the endpoint you are calling doesn't return a `.success` property, you cannot use that to determine if the call was successful or not.

Is there any other data in the response that indicates if it was successful or not?

If not, perhaps you can just assume that a non-error response is successful, and catch errors in the error handler:

```js
  onBlogSubmit() {
    const post = {
      postTitle: this.postTitle,
      postAuthor: this.postAuthor,
      postContent: this.postContent,
      postImgUrl: this.postImgUrl
    }

    this.postService.addPost(post).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.postService.getPosts();
            this.flashMessage.show('Blog Submitted Successfully', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000});
            this.router.navigate(['/blog-page']);
        },
        error => {
            this.flashMessage.show('Something Went Wrong', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your answer actually half solved my problem. The post gets successfully submitted. But it doesn't show in the mat-card component with the Author, Title and Content etc.

Comment: goood.  one step closer :-)  You must have a mismatch between the data shape being returned, and the shape you are trying to use.  Do `console.log(posts)` to see what the real data shape is, and ensure your template is using that same shape.

Comment: The console.log(posts) just show me an _id value and updated value. It doesn't display the content, author or title. The mat-card also returns empty. I want it to show the title, author and content. But how can I show them??

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with your `blog-page`.

**Correction:**

**HTML:**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div *ngFor="let post of posts" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <mat-card class="card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title class="title">{{post.postTitle}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle class="subtitle">Author: {{post.postAuthor}}</mat-card-subtitle>
      <mat-card-subtitle class="subtitle">Content: {{post.postContent}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-actions class="multi-button">
      <button mat-icon-button><span class="fa fa-share fa-lg"></span></button>
      <button mat-icon-button><span class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></span></button>
      <!-- <button mat-icon-button><span class="fa fa-heart fa-lg"></span></button> -->
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { PostService } from "../post.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-blog-page",
  templateUrl: "./blog-page.component.html"
  styleUrls: ["./blog-page.component.scss"]
})
export class BlogPageComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: Object;

  constructor(private postService: PostService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(
      posts => {
        console.log(posts);
        this.posts = posts;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Working demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jozk1y?file=src/app/blog-page/blog-page.component.html).

**Note:** I've commented on some of your components and mocked your API. Please use your real API to test.

**Edit:**

Also change the HTML of `blog-add` component:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="row" *ngIf="post">
  <div class="col-sm-12 form-main">
      <form name="postForm" (ngsubmit)="onBlogSubmit()" class="text-center border border-light p-5 shadow-lg">

        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="postTitle" name="postTitle">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="postAuthor" name="postAuthor">
          <img ng-src="postImgUrl">
          <ckeditor matCkeditor class="form-control mb-8" [(ngModel)]="postContent" name="postContent"></ckeditor>
          <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block get" (click)="onBlogSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works fine for hardcoded data. But console.log(posts) returns only an _id and updated value. It does not return the title, content and author. The content, title and author return empty when I submit the blog post as well. How can I solve this??

Comment: Change the blog-add component.

Comment: And if you still got a problem, please upload the project at StackBlitz.